# How can I retrieve screen unlock times in Gnome on later Red Hat variants?

Tags: rhel, gnome, logs, pam

The `last` command only retrieves the login times. I'm interested in the times that the screen was unlocked. Any indirect means of getting this are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this method discussed on SO in this Q&A titled: [How can I log my logins/logouts and screen locks/unlocks in gnome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942184/how-can-i-log-my-logins-logouts-and-screen-locks-unlocks-in-gnome). Below are the detail from that post.

---

#### autostart

The method makes use of this autostart `.desktop` config file that you'd drop in this directory: `$HOME/.config/autostart/watcher.sh.desktop`.

```
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/watcher.sh.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/<username>/path/to/watcher/watcher.sh
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de_DE]=watcher
Name=watcher
Comment[de_DE]=
Comment=
```

#### watch.sh

The `watch.sh` script takes arguments so you'll need to include those in the `Exec=` line above. Here's an example of what the `watcher.sh` can look like:

```
$ cat watch.sh
#!/bin/bash
# param $1: type, in:
#     ["SCREEN_LOCKED",
#     "SCREEN_UNLOCKED",
#     "LOGIN",
#     "LOGOUT",
#     "SIGINT",
#     "SIGTERM"]
function write_log {
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    1="unspecified"
  fi
  echo -e "$1\t$(date)" >> "$LOG"
}

function notify {
  echo "$@" >&2
}

function show_usage {
  notify "Usage: $0 login <address> <logfile>"
  notify "Parameters:"
  notify "  login: You must use the string 'login' to avoid seeing this message."
  notify "  <logfile>: File to store logs."
  notify ""
  notify "This script is designed to go in the bashrc file, and be called in the"
  notify "form of: $0 login '$USER@$(uname -n)' >>/path/to/logfile &"
  notify ""
}

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  show_usage
  exit 1
fi
if [ "$1" != "login" ]; then
  show_usage
  notify "Error: first parameter must be the string 'login'."
  exit 1
fi
LOG="$2"
if [ -z "$LOG" ]; then
  notify "Error: please specify a logfile."
  exit 1
elif [ -f "$LOG" ]; then
  # If the logfile exists, verify that the last action was a LOGOUT.
  LASTACTION=$(tail -1 "$LOG" | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $LASTACTION != "LOGOUT" ]; then
    notify "Logfile '$LOG' exists but last action was not logout: $LASTACTION"
    exit 1
  fi
else
  # If the file does not exist, create it.
  touch "$LOG" || ( notify "Cannot create logfile: '$2'" && exit 1 )
fi

# Begin by logging in:
write_log "LOGIN"

# Handle signals by logging:
trap "write_log 'LOGOUT'; exit" SIGHUP
trap "write_log 'INTERRUPTED_SIGINT'; exit 1" SIGINT
trap "write_log 'INTERRUPTED_SIGTERM'; exit 1" SIGTERM

# Monitor gnome for screen locking. Log these events.
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | \
  (
    while true; do
      read X;
      if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
        write_log "SCREEN_LOCKED"
      elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then
        write_log "SCREEN_UNLOCKED"
      fi
    done
  )
```

With the script in place when you login it will output entries to whatever log file was included in the `Exec=` line that you specify.

```
Exec="/path/to/watcher.sh login someuser.log >> error.log"
```

#### Example

You can simulate running it via the command line directly:

```
$ ./watcher.bash login someuser.log  >> smurf.log &
[1] 20684
```

If you lock your screen and then unlock you'll see messages like these:

```
$ more someuser.log 
LOGIN   Fri Mar  7 20:16:29 EST 2014
SCREEN_LOCKED   Fri Mar  7 20:25:48 EST 2014
SCREEN_UNLOCKED Fri Mar  7 20:28:02 EST 2014
SCREEN_UNLOCKED Fri Mar  7 20:28:03 EST 2014
INTERRUPTED_SIGINT  Fri Mar  7 21:44:46 EST 2014
```

**NOTE:** The script's "LOGIN" message above is from when you invoke the script. I aborted the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which generated the "INTERRUPTED_SIGINT" message via one of the traps in the `watch.sh` script. If I had logged out it would've shown a message that I "LOGOUT".